# Go Error: time.Time does not implement driver.Valuer (missing method Value)

Tags: sqlite, go, graphql, sqlboiler

I'm working on a Go project where I'm using sqlboiler to generate code from a SQLite3 database that I created with a setup.sh script. I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to resolve. The error message is:

```
graph/db/repositories.go:998:23: cannot use o.CreatedAt (variable of type string) as driver.Valuer value in argument to queries.MustTime: string does not implement driver.Valuer (missing method Value)
graph/db/repositories.go:999:23: cannot use &o.CreatedAt (value of type *string) as sql.Scanner value in argument to queries.SetScanner: *string does not implement sql.Scanner (missing method Scan)
```

This error occurs when I try to use a time.Time value in my graph/db/repositories.go file. I'm using the golang:1.21-alpine3.18 Docker image for my project.

I've tried changing the created_at column type in the repositories table in my SQLite3 database. I've tested it with both TEXT and TIMESTAMP data types, but the error still persists.

Does anyone know what could be causing this error and how I can resolve it?

repositories.go

```
func (o *Repository) Insert(ctx context.Context, exec boil.ContextExecutor, columns boil.Columns) error {
    if o == nil {
        return errors.New("db: no repositories provided for insertion")
    }

    var err error
    if !boil.TimestampsAreSkipped(ctx) {
        currTime := time.Now().In(boil.GetLocation())

        if queries.MustTime(o.CreatedAt).IsZero() {
            queries.SetScanner(&o.CreatedAt, currTime)
        }
    }

    if err := o.doBeforeInsertHooks(ctx, exec); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    nzDefaults := queries.NonZeroDefaultSet(repositoryColumnsWithDefault, o)

    key := makeCacheKey(columns, nzDefaults)
    repositoryInsertCacheMut.RLock()
    cache, cached := repositoryInsertCache[key]
    repositoryInsertCacheMut.RUnlock()
```

setup.sh

```
#!/usr/local/bin/sh

set -eu

readonly DBFILE_NAME="mygraphql.db"

# Create DB file
if [ ! -e ${DBFILE_NAME} ];then
  echo ".open ${DBFILE_NAME}" | sqlite3
fi

# Create DB Tables
echo "creating tables..."
sqlite3 ${DBFILE_NAME} "
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(\
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,\
    name TEXT NOT NULL,\
    project_v2 TEXT\
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS repositories(\
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,\
    owner TEXT NOT NULL,\
    name TEXT NOT NULL,\
    created_at TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT (DATETIME('now','localtime')),\
    FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES users(id)\
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS issues(\
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,\
    url TEXT NOT NULL,\
    title TEXT NOT NULL,\
    closed INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,\
    number INTEGER NOT NULL,\
    repository TEXT NOT NULL,\
    CHECK (closed IN (0, 1)),\
    FOREIGN KEY (repository) REFERENCES repositories(id)\
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects(\
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,\
    title TEXT NOT NULL,\
    url TEXT NOT NULL,\
    owner TEXT NOT NULL,\
    FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES users(id)\
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pullrequests(\
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,\
    base_ref_name TEXT NOT NULL,\
    closed INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,\
    head_ref_name TEXT NOT NULL,\
    url TEXT NOT NULL,\
    number INTEGER NOT NULL,\
    repository TEXT NOT NULL,\
    CHECK (closed IN (0, 1)),\
    FOREIGN KEY (repository) REFERENCES repositories(id)\
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projectcards(\
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,\
    project TEXT NOT NULL,\
    issue TEXT,\
    pullrequest TEXT,\
    FOREIGN KEY (project) REFERENCES projects(id),\
    FOREIGN KEY (issue) REFERENCES issues(id),\
    FOREIGN KEY (pullrequest) REFERENCES pullrequests(id),\
    CHECK (issue IS NOT NULL OR pullrequest IS NOT NULL)\
);
"

# Insert initial data
echo "inserting initial data..."
sqlite3 ${DBFILE_NAME} "
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

INSERT INTO users(id, name) VALUES\
    ('U_1', 'hsaki')
;

INSERT INTO repositories(id, owner, name) VALUES\
    ('REPO_1', 'U_1', 'repo1')
;

INSERT INTO issues(id, url, title, closed, number, repository) VALUES\
    ('ISSUE_1', 'http://example.com/repo1/issue/1', 'First Issue', 1, 1, 'REPO_1'),\
    ('ISSUE_2', 'http://example.com/repo1/issue/2', 'Second Issue', 0, 2, 'REPO_1'),\
    ('ISSUE_3', 'http://example.com/repo1/issue/3', 'Third Issue', 0, 3, 'REPO_1')\
;

INSERT INTO projects(id, title, url, owner) VALUES\
    ('PJ_1', 'My Project', 'http://example.com/project/1', 'U_1')\
;

INSERT INTO pullrequests(id, base_ref_name, closed, head_ref_name, url, number, repository) VALUES\
    ('PR_1', 'main', 1, 'feature/kinou1', 'http://example.com/repo1/pr/1', 1, 'REPO_1'),\
    ('PR_2', 'main', 0, 'feature/kinou2', 'http://example.com/repo1/pr/2', 2, 'REPO_1')\
;
"
```

sqlboiler.toml

```
pkgname="db"
output="graph/db"
wipe=true
add-global-variants=false
no-tests=true

[sqlite3]
  dbname = "./mygraphql.db"
```

Environment

```
・ MacBook Pro M1 Pro
```

Comment: the code works fine see https://dbfiddle.uk/3E9nCtz- , but what is the exact and complete  error message

Comment: It says `o.CreatedAt (variable of type string)` - it sounds like you think o.CreatedAt is a time.Time but the error indicates otherwise

Answer (score 1):

It worked well. I changed the type of 'created_at' in the repositories of setup.sh to DATETIME and regenerated it. Thank you for your assistance below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS repositories(\
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,\
    owner TEXT NOT NULL,\
    name TEXT NOT NULL,\
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (DATETIME('now','localtime')),\
    FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES users(id)\
);
```